# How to share forder between several users?

Tags: permissions, groups

I want to share a folder between several users of my computer. How do i do that?

For example, i have a folder `/home/user1/project`, and i want to put it into `/usr/share/devel` (devel is new), and make it fully accessible to the `user2`. What is the sequence of commands to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give all users r/w/x permission on the directory:

```
chmod -R guo+rwx /path/to/shared/directory
```

If you only want to enable certain users to use the directory, then create a new user group, add all authorized users to it: (All these commands require root/sudo)

```
#Create group
groupadd projectshare
#Add users to the group. Execute for each user:
usermod -a -G projectshare <username>
#Assign group as owner of directory
chown -R <yourusername>:projectshare /path/to/shared/directory
#Assign file permissions:
chmod -R ug+rwx /path/to/shared/directory
```

Now all members of the group have full access to the directory and everything in it.

Comment: What does RUO+X mean? what are those flags? Thanks!

Comment: @MiguelStevens g: usergroup with ownership, u: user with ownership, o: every other user/group. r: read permission, w: write permission, x: execution permission (for directories: permission to view content). The + means that `rwx` are being allowed to `guo`. A - would deny these again. guo+rwx results in a file permission of 0777.